# I implemented a star rating system for delivery man in django by users but i am stuck at how to calculate the average

Tags: django

I have a model name Ratings and its connected to custom user model through foreignkey relationship.i used javascript to post data and get ratings in the backend by get method using id but the problem is rating process works fine but it just upgrades the current queryset when ever regarded delivery man gets rated. so how do i calculatye the average as it does not store the previous querysets rather its just upgrades the queryset of that particular deliveryman

views.py

```
def rate_user(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    el_id = request.POST.get('el_id')
    val = request.POST.get('val')
    print(val)
    obj = Ratings.objects.get(id=el_id)
    obj.rated_number = val
    obj.save()
    return JsonResponse({'success':'true', 'score': val}, safe=False)
return JsonResponse({'success':'false'})
```

models.py

```
class Ratings(models.Model):
    rated_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    avg_rating = models.CharField(max_length=5,null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    # count = models.CharField(max_length=100000,blank=True,null=True,default=0)
    rated_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0,
        validators = [
             MaxValueValidator(5),
             MinValueValidator(1),
        ]
   )
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
    
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_ratings(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.is_delivery_man or instance.is_driver:
            Ratings.objects.create(rated_user=instance)
```

js

```
<script>
    const one = document.getElementById('first')
    const two = document.getElementById('second')
    const three = document.getElementById('third')
    const four = document.getElementById('fourth')
    const five = document.getElementById('fifth')

    // get the form, confirm-box and csrf token
    const form = document.querySelector('.rate-form')
    const confirmBox = document.getElementById('confirm-box')
    const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')

    const handleStarSelect = (size) => {
        const children = form.children
        console.log(children[0])
        for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            if (i <= size) {
                children[i].classList.add('checked')
            } else {
                children[i].classList.remove('checked')
            }
        }
    }

    const handleSelect = (selection) => {
        switch (selection) {
            case 'first': {
                handleStarSelect(1)
                return
            }
            case 'second': {
                handleStarSelect(2)
                return
            }
            case 'third': {
                handleStarSelect(3)
                return
            }
            case 'fourth': {
                handleStarSelect(4)
                return
            }
            case 'fifth': {
                handleStarSelect(5)
                return
            }
            default: {
                handleStarSelect(0)
            }
        }

    }

    const getNumericValue = (stringValue) => {
        let numericValue;
        if (stringValue === 'first') {
            numericValue = 1
        }
        else if (stringValue === 'second') {
            numericValue = 2
        }
        else if (stringValue === 'third') {
            numericValue = 3
        }
        else if (stringValue === 'fourth') {
            numericValue = 4
        }
        else if (stringValue === 'fifth') {
            numericValue = 5
        }
        else {
            numericValue = 0
        }
        return numericValue
    }

    if (one) {
        const arr = [one, two, three, four, five]

        arr.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
            handleSelect(event.target.id)
        }))

        arr.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            // value of the rating not numeric
            const val = event.target.id

            let isSubmit = false
            form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
                e.preventDefault()
                if (isSubmit) {
                    return
                }
                isSubmit = true
                // rate id
                const id = e.target.id
                // value of the rating translated into numeric
                const val_num = getNumericValue(val)

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/rate/',
                    data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf[0].value,
                        'el_id': id,
                        'val': val_num,
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response)
                        confirmBox.innerHTML = `<h1>Successfully rated with ${response.score} star</h1>`
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                        confirmBox.innerHTML = '<h1>Ups... something went wrong</h1>'
                    }
                })
            })
        }))
    }
</script>
```

Form

```
    {%for i in ratings%}
    <a href="#" >Average Ratings: {{i.rated_number}}</a><br><br>
    i class="fas fa-vote-yea"></i> Rate this user <br>
     <form class="rate-form" action="" method="POST" id={{i.id}}>
    {% csrf_token %}
   <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-3x my-btn" id="first"></button>
   <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-3x my-btn" id="second"></button>
   <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-3x my-btn" id="third"></button>
   <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-3x my-btn" id="fourth"></button>
   <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-3x my-btn" id="fifth"></button>
   </form>
   {%endfor%}
    <br>
    <div id="confirm-box"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: The modeling looks quite strange: the average is stored in the `Rating` itself? There is no reference to the item that has been rated? The average is a `CharField`?

Comment: yes there is reference i mean i am rating users and it works..i am just stuck at how to find the average as it does not makes new querysets ..it just upgrades the rated value when ever the rated_user is been rated by other user.if you can help me on that please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally waiting for answer from stackoverflow i got tired and started debugging myself and i ended up with an nice mathmetical algorithm to achieve my desired goal and i think i have achieved it except it doest show or take values after decimal. avg are coming with a round shape .

i just changed a field in my model to store previous and now all rating number addition

```
class Ratings(models.Model):

rated_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
storing_prev_now_rated_value = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=1)
avg_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=1)
count = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
rated_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=1,
    validators = [
        MaxValueValidator(5),
        MinValueValidator(1),
    ]
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.rated_user.username
```

and i have changes in my views.py too

```
def rate_user(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    el_id = request.POST.get('el_id')
    val = request.POST.get('val')
    print(val)
    obj = Ratings.objects.get(id=el_id)

    storing_prev_rated_number = obj.rated_number

    obj.rated_number = val

    obj.count = obj.count + 1
    store_count = obj.count
    old_addition_values = obj.storing_prev_now_rated_value

    obj.storing_prev_now_rated_value = int(old_addition_values) + int(val)

    store_storing_prev_now_rated_value = obj.storing_prev_now_rated_value
    print(store_storing_prev_now_rated_value)

    obj.avg_rating = float(store_storing_prev_now_rated_value // store_count)

    j  = obj.avg_rating
    print(j)
    obj.save()
    return JsonResponse({'success':'true', 'rated_number': val}, safe=False)
return JsonResponse({'success':'false'})
```